# btrfs device don't mount, probably a raid, how to check it?

Tags: btrfs

When a btrfs device is mounted is easy to know if is a raid or not

```
btrfs filesystem df /
```

In this situation the fs don't mount, probably is a raid

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

dmesg said

```
[ven nov 10 18:00:10 2023] BTRFS error (device sdc2): devid 1 uuid bf113911-2436-4976-a590-6b14c16445e0 is missing
[ven nov 10 18:00:10 2023] BTRFS error (device sdc2): failed to read the system array: -2
[ven nov 10 18:00:10 2023] BTRFS error (device sdc2): open_ctree failed
```

mount with degraded don't work, so is probably a raid5 or 6, how to know the configuration?

btrfs device stats failed

```
btrfs device stats /dev/sdc2
ERROR: '/dev/sdc2' is not a mounted btrfs device
```

those commands failed

```
btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree /dev/sdc2
btrfs property get /dev/sdc2
```